# Minimize cost from gradient descent algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, backpropagation, gradient-descent

I'm working on an optimization problem. My function is like this: `C=-σ(wx+b)+σ(wθz+b)` where `σ` is a sigmoid function. What I'm doing here is to find an optimal value of `w` and `b` so that my cost `C` can keep minimizing nearest to zero.

I assume x,θ and z as constant value, based on the gradient algorithm, first initialize w and b and calculate the cost, and then update w, b from back propagation to get a smaller cost value(cost can be negative, but I think only how close to 0 would matter.)

I'm quite stuck here because I keep getting increased cost, I think there is something wrong about the gradient. Can anyone provide some suggestions?

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def sigmoid_prime(x):
    """ sigmoid derivative """
    return x * (1.0-x)

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1/(1 + np.exp(-x))

cost_list = []
x = 1
z = 7.5
w = 0.001
b = 0.01
theta = 0.002
lrt = 0.01

for i in range(50):
    y = sigmoid(w*x+b)
    fake = sigmoid(w*theta*z + b)
    cost = -y+fake
    #calculate gradient descent to update w,b 
    dw = - sigmoid_prime(y) * x +  sigmoid_prime(fake) * theta*z
    db = - sigmoid_prime(y) +  sigmoid_prime(fake)

    w += lrt * dw
    b += lrt * db

    cost_list.append(cost)

plt.plot(cost_list)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like a sign flip maybe.

Comment: Your derivatives don't look correct (both the `sigmoid_prime` and the derivatives of your cost).

Comment: I tried to update w through w- = lrt * dw, but the cost gets smaller and smaller which deviates from zero. Is there a way to flip to zero...?

Comment: Btw, what do you expect? The function does not seem to have a minimum and the root can simply be achieved by setting `w=0, b=0`.

Comment: @NicoSchertler: Hi Nico, you are right if directly setting `w=0, b=0`, job is done. I'm trying to simulate the gradient descent and observe that the cost is approaching to zero. Can you elaborate more on `sigmoid_prime` and the derivatives? Thanks

Comment: Gradient descent does not find zeros. It finds local minima. And your function apparently does not have any. To find roots, you can use Newton's method. There isn't much to elaborate on the derivatives. They are just wrong (check e.g. Wolfram Alpha to find the correct derivatives if you don't want to calculate them yourself).